# PHP - make a normalised keyword table

Tags: php, many-to-many

I have a mysql db with an **article** (article_id, keyword) db table where keywords is a comma-separated list. I have created two new empty tables:

**keywords** (keyword_id, keyword) where each row has only one keyword.

**article_key** (article_id, keyword_id) where each row has only one keyword.

Thus I want to have a many-to-many relationship from articles to keywords. I wanted to create a short script to extract the id and keywords from the original **article** table, split the keywords and populate the two new tables appropriately. I assumed this would be easy, but has proved a little more tricky than I thought.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: this *is* actually quite easy. what's the problem?

Comment: **article_key** (article id, keyword) should probably be **article_key** (article id, keyword id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something similar to this:

```
//Get articles with keywords:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT article_id, keyword FROM article");

//Cycle through all articles
while ($article = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $article_id = $article['article_id'];
     $keywords = $article['keyword'];
     //Explode keywords on seperator (; in this case)
     $keyword_array = explode(";", $keywords);

     //For each keyword get the corresponding ID
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($keyword_array); i++) {
          $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT keyword_id FROM keywords WHERE keyword = '" . $keyword_array[$i] . "'");
          //Get keyword_id
          $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
          $keyword_id = $row['keyword_id'];

          //Insert new key
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO article_key VALUES (" . $article_id . ", " . $keyword_id . ")");
     }
}
```

In this script (not tested) I assumed you already have your **keywords** table filled with the keywords, and that your **article** table contains a comma seperated list of **KEYWORDS** and **NOT** id's.

Comment: Yes, I did have to populate the keywords table first. Having done that though @Jules's answer was pretty close to what I need. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code:

```
$keywords = "kw1,kw2,kw3,...";
foreach(explode(',', $keywords) as $kw) {
   INSERT IGNORE keywords (keyword) VALUES ('$kw')
   $id = mysql_insert_id();
   INSERT INTO article_key (article_id, keyword) VALUES ($aID, $id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your question is, and I'm assuming that in `article_key` you meant `keyword_id` rather than `keyword`

To get the keywords of an article (given article_id):

```
SELECT keywords.keyword 
FROM keywords
    INNER JOIN article_key ON keywords.keyword_id = article_key.keyword_id 
WHERE article_id = ?
```

To get the articles that a keyword is associated with (given keyword_id):

```
SELECT article_id
FROM article_keys 
    INNER JOIN keywords ON keywords.keyword_id = article_key.keyword_id
WHERE keyword = ?
```

**Edit**

Missed your actual question, just saw it though.  Marc B's answer below is a good one.